# Convert IP address to a website name

Tags: ip-address, wampserver, intranet

I have created a website and want to make it an intranet site for my home network. I am using a WAMP Server as my local sever . The issue that I am struggling with is assigning an IP address to a website name or intranet name. Example I want to give IP address 10.68.10.50 to http://myhome.jnb.ei. How do I make such changes on the Wamp server?

Comment: http://www.complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-localhost-to-a-domain-name

Comment: write it in host file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you go about it this way as such. What I have done is to rather use the hosts file to direct the local computers to the website.

For example, assuming that the IP address of the computer hosting wampserver is 10.68.10.50. Then for each computer edit the hosts file to include:-

10.68.10.50 www.myhome.jnb.ei

For windows 7 the hosts file is in .../Windows/System32/Drivers/etc and is called **hosts**

This basically means that by typing www.myhome.jnb.ei in the browser that you get directed to the apache server at 10.68.10.50.

You can do a similar thing with Linux computers, it's just that the hosts file is in a Linux specific location etc/ I think.